# Facebook Graph API - Post a photo in an album with page admin access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

**CONTEXT**

So I have this Facebook page where I sell baby products. Every now and then we organize a photo contest as it has been proven an effective way to engage with the customers/community. Previously, we used to get photos from the customers and manually upload each and every one of them in an album.

**Problem**
Automate the process of

1. Getting an image from the customer
2. Uploading them into the album
3. Provide the customer with the URL

with: 
The customer being able to upload the image on a UI(form as attached below) from the website which should upload the image in the Facebook album and return the URL back to them via Graph API.  [Not sure if its a good idea, please feel free to advise :) ]

This is what I've built:
[image]

**QUESTION**

What should be the flow of getting the permanent access token where the customer won't have to log in. Maybe get a PageAccessToken with reading and write permission and process the automation from there?
What would your flow be if this case scenario? I want to avoid the customer having to log in as we don't need their data at all. All I need is them to post the photo in the album of my page.
Being new to the FB Graph API, I would really appreciate a step by step approach to solve the problem.

I am using VUE JS and Facebook JS SDK.
Backend PHP..
Cheers!

Comment: You can not do this any other way, than by using a page token. How to get them, how to extend them - all explained in the documentation.

Comment: _“Not sure if its a good idea”_ - all those uploads would happen in the name of your page - so your page is responsible for what gets posted. Let that be a couple of nude pics or anything else Facebook does not like … and in the worst case scenario, your page could get blocked over it.

Comment: Yes i have spend couple of hours in the documentation, hence i am here as i need a clear idea... i feel like the documentation isnt straight enough for me to understand.. the link are taking me everywhere but to the right direction.. would you be kind enough to provide me a step by step process in the answers section so that i can pick that as a right answer and close this thread? This may help others like me who got distracted and lost in the documentation too..

Comment: Or an idea with what would be your solution to my problem even?

Comment: _“I am using VUE JS and Facebook JS SDK.”_ - doing this purely client-side, is not an option to begin with. That would mean, you would need to expose your page token to outsiders in client-side code, which is an absolute no-go to begin with. If you want to implement anything like this, then the API request part must be handled on the server side.

Comment: Oh yes I am using PHP as a backend...

Comment: A page admin will have to login to your app, and grant it `pages_show_list` and `pages_manage_posts` permissions. Then you use their user token, to request a page token for the page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing#get-a-long-lived-page-access-token

Comment: And of course you will have to submit your app for review of its usage of those permissions, before you can use it in production mode. (While in dev mode, all content created through it, will only be visible to people with a role in the app in the first place.) Although, not sure if Facebook would approve an app with such a purpose and functionality. If they see that you are letting outsiders post in the name of your page, they might decline that right away.

Comment: So are you suggesting that possibly there is no way to automate this? 

Comment: I don’t think Facebook will approve this, if you just let any “rando” post content directly onto your page, _as_ your page. You could probably get this through, by submitting it as a server-to-server app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps - if you _don’t_ tell them that you will post user content directly. Phrase it as “publishing photos from your CMS backend ” or something, then it might go through. That would be somewhat cheating the system then, of course.

Comment: Nice.. I think what I really need is server to server app.. what i can do is get the user data from the form above and save it to db... later run the crob job to do the automation.. and i guess thats not cheating at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached the conclusion after a few research and suggestions provided by @CBroe that designing the app like the way I initially imagined is not very practical and here is what I have decided to do:

1. The customers will be able to send the required information by filling the form
2. The information will be saved in a database including the image
3. The first thing will be to generate a user access token
4. Generate Long-lived user access token
5. Generate Long-lived page access token
6. I have decided, instead of pushing the photo directly to Facebook, it'll be first approved by the admin
7. If everything alright the admin will post it to the Facebook album with a push of a button

So, my solution is to automate posting to the Facebook where the admin has to push a approve button instead of the customer being able to directly post the photo on Facebook. I will try to post a link to git after it's done.